# Centering model for symmetrization

Tags: modeling, object-mode

Have a human model that I moved in both object mode and edit mode and have no idea how to re-center it. There are multiple vertices on the top of the head that mark the point of symmetry and one between the feet. Sorry if a noob question.[image]

Comment: Please show your work in form of a Blender Screen capture.  Show as much meaning as you can.

Comment: Not sure how to add multiple pictures. Kept replacing the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the object (while you are in object mode) and then click on set origin -> set origin to geometry. Then your origin is going to be centered again

Comment: There is still the matter of rotation. I can get the model in the center no prob but it’s still rotated even though all numbers are set to zero.

Comment: Use Alt + R to get the model rotate to its default state as it was before making the changes.